# LabelEncoder in sklearn throws value comparison error

Tags: python, pandas

I get the error "'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'" when executing the below code. The error message does not even say in which column is the error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for column in df8.columns:
  if df8[column].dtype == type(object):
    df8[column] = le.fit_transform(df8[column])
```

Comment: Check whether your data Contain NaN ?

Comment: @Wen: Yes it has. But I have replaced it using df8=df8.fillna("")

Comment: Is this work ? df8[column] = le.fit_transform(df8[column].astype(str)

Comment: @Wen: Thank you, but this did not work as well

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below the snippet you have provided works. I also tried your method of filling NaNs and it still works. It might be worth restarting your IDE and checking what else your data frame contains.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Country':['China', 'India', 'USA', 'Indonesia', 'Brasil', 'Japan'],
         'Population, M': [1403.5, 1324.2, 322.2, 261.1, 207.6, 127.6],
         'Label': ['huge', 'huge', 'big', 'big', 'big', 'big']})

print(df)

le = LabelEncoder()
for column in df.columns:
  if df[column].dtype == type(object):
    df[column] = le.fit_transform(df[column])

print(df)

     Country Label  Population, M
0      China  huge         1403.5
1      India  huge         1324.2
2        USA   big          322.2
3  Indonesia   big          261.1
4     Brasil   big          207.6
5      Japan   big          127.6
Out[78]: 
   Country  Label  Population, M
0        1      1         1403.5
1        2      1         1324.2
2        5      0          322.2
3        3      0          261.1
4        0      0          207.6
5        4      0          127.6
```